# DynamicModule Error when assigning Nothing to variable

Tags: bugs, dynamic, warning-messages, scoping, hold

Assigning `Nothing` to a variable inside `Module` works as expected:

```
Module[{x, y},
 x = 1;
 y = Nothing;
 {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {1}
> ```

However, using `DynamicModule` instead triggers an error:

```
DynamicModule[{x, y},
 x = 1;
 y = Nothing;
 {x, y}]
```

> ```
> Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {{Hold[x],Hold[y]},{Hold[1]}} cannot be transposed.
> ```

> ```
> Manipulate`Dump`eDynamicModule[
> Transpose[
> Manipulate`Dump`heldsetting[{{Hold[x], Hold[y]}, {Hold[1]}}]], {1}, 
> DynamicModuleValues :> {}]
> ```

I came across this error combining `DynamicModule` with `Manipulate`, getting a different error message:

```
DynamicModule[{x, y},
 Manipulate[
  x = 1;
  y = Nothing;
  {x, y, z},
  {z, 1, 10}]]
```

> ```
> MapThread::mptc: Incompatible dimensions of objects at positions {2, 2} and {2, 3} of
> MapThread[FrontEnd`Private`newvalue,
> {{1,2},
>   {Hold[FE`x$$367],Hold[FE`y$$367]},
>   {Hold[1]},
>   {Hold[1]}}
> ]; dimensions are 2 and 1.
> ```

[image: Screenshot of Mathematica output]

Now of course one can easily work around these errors, e.g. writing

```
DynamicModule[{x, y},
 x = 1;
 If[IWantToReturnNothing[], {x}, {x, y}],
 Initialization :> (IWantToReturnNothing[] := True)]
```

> ```
> {1}
> ```

where the function `IWantToReturnNothing[]` evaluates whether I want to assign `Nothing` to the variable $y$. So I am not asking for a solution/workaround, I am just curious as to why this happens to better understand Mathematica. I suspect this behaviour has to do with the point of time `Hold` is released from `Hold[Nothing]`, but I don't know why Mathematica would release `Hold` before initialization?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: I'll report this with the appropriate development team. Something is certainly going wrong here.